# No me aparecen los dato de la tabla en mi CRUD

Tags: php, mysql, php7, crud

Estoy haciendo un `CRUD` con `PHP` y `MySQL` y no me aparecen los datos en la tabla.

**Archivo conexión**:

```
PHP
$conn = mysqli_connect(
  'localhost',
  'root',
  '',
  'crud_php'
);
```

**Archivo listar**:

```
PHP
include_once("conexion.php");

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `personas`";

  $sentencia = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

**Archivo index**:

```
<!-- registros de la bbdd -->
    <?php include_once("listar.php"); ?>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sentencia)) { ?>

      <tr>
        <td><?php  echo $row['id'] ?></td>
        <td><<?php echo $row['nombre'] ?></td>
        <td><<?php echo $row["apellidos"] ?></td>
        <td><<?php echo $row['genero'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['DNI'] ?></td>
      </tr>

    <?php } ?>
```

**Tabla**:

```
MYSQL
id   nombre    apellido  genero DNI
1    carlos     gomez      m   52679523
2    camila     gonzales   f    45326854
```

Al ejecutar eso me imprime la columna `id` y `dni`, la columna `nombre`, `apellido` y `genero` no me las imprime. Intente ver varios videos pero la verdad utilizan la versión vieja de php y como la mayoría de las funciones están obsoletas no sé que hacer.

Comment: Como es la estructura de tu base de datos?

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($row);` para ver cómo se llaman las columnas. Otra cosa que podría estar pasando es que la tabla tenga otros encabezados o celdas dispares anterior al `while`. Por favor edita la pregunta y pon el título en letras normales, hay que evitar el uso indiscriminado de mayúsculas. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Quizá sea porque se te escapa un caracter `<` en la siempre confusa mezcla de código HTML/PHP.

Particularmente recomiendo evitar esa mezcla, haciendo usa de una variable y de la concatenación. Por ejemplo:

```
<?php 
    include_once("listar.php");
    #Antes del bucle declaramos la variable que usaremos para concatenar
    $html="";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sentencia)) { 
        #OJO aquí al uso de .= que sirve para concatenar en PHP
        #En los <td> usamos indices sin comillas simples (ver punto 3 más abajo)
        $html.="<tr>
                    <td>$row[id]</td>
                    <td>$row[nombre]</td>
                    <td>$row[apellidos]</td>
                    <td>$row[genero]</td>
                    <td>$row[DNI]</td>
                </tr>";
    }
    #Imprimos los datos concatenados una vez terminado el while
    echo $html; 
?>
```

Para entender lo que se ha hecho y sus ventajas:

1. Todo el código se encuentra dentro de solo bloque PHP. Es más claro, más legible y menos propenso a errores.
2. Para poder permanecer dentro del mismo bloque, sin constantes aperturas y cierres y sin el constante uso de `echo`, usamos una variable `$html` a la que le vamos concatenando las diferentes filas.
3. Algo fundamental es usar las comillas dobles para delimitar las filas que se irán recogiendo en el `while`. Eso nos permite usar variables dentro sin constantes concatenaciones con el punto (`.`). Además nos permite, para este caso concreto, hacer referencia a los índices de `$row` sin las comillas simples, aportando mucha más claridad al código.
4. Finalmente, se imprime `$html` al salir del bucle `while`.

Esta es la forma más clara de proceder en casos como estos.

Si aún así no funciona, revisa si las columnas se llaman así realmente, puedes hacer un `var_dump($row);` para verificar los datos.

Otra cosa que podría hacer que no funcione es que en tu elemento `<table>` haya columnas dispares más arriba. Yo supongo que todo el manejo de apertura y cierre de `<table>` lo tienes controlado.

Comment: Señor lo ame, funciona, MUCHAS GRACIAS.